# What is the origin of "uh", "um", "erm" and "er"?

Tags: etymology, language-evolution, rhoticity, dialogue

This question may be a better fit on linguistics.SE, but it pertains specifically to English [fillers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_%28linguistics%29). Also, the question may have a more straightforward answer than what I'm expecting.

**TL;DR: Are these fillers mimetic or trace to other languages? Where are they first recorded in English?**

First off, although I've always pronounced them differently, the Wiktionary entry for [*er*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/er) has the pronunciation for non-rhotic dialects (/ɜ, /ə in ODO), comparing it to *uh* (/ʌ, /ʌh). Would this be a very similar sound? I'm skeptical as to whether or not this points to a common heritage. Furthermore, the usual sources show *er* occurred more recently<sup>[[1]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=er&allowed_in_frame=0)[[2]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/er?q=er)</sup> than *uh* or *um*.<sup>[[3]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uh&allowed_in_frame=0)[[4]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=um&allowed_in_frame=0)</sup>

I run into confusion when [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uh&allowed_in_frame=0) states that *uh* is "attested c.1600" whereas [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uh?q=uh) puts its origin in the 1960s. Perhaps it's because ODO is focused on modern usage. All sources I've seen ascribe the words to natural utterances. However, if they are purely mimetic, this doesn't explain why filler sounds differ so widely across languages (i.e. why doesn't every language have these fillers or vice-versa).

Based on the fillers of other languages, one might conclude these English fillers were influenced by the Welsh *ym* or German *äh* (/ɛː/) or *hm*. Or is this a case of false cognates because "m" is [easily produced](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilabial_nasal)?

Either way, how do we know *uh* and *um* go back to the 17th century since I'd hazard a guess that "realistic dialogue" (recorded on the page) is relatively "new" (no earlier than 1800s)?

Comment: What's next, a question about the origin of "ow"?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I also consider that an interesting question insofar as other languages use different exclamations (e.g. Japanese *itai*  or *ite* (lit. "painful") similar to *ouch* in English). Are these constructs onomatopoeic or did the semantic association with an arbitrary sound come first (only to later become a "learned reflex" to pain). However, the topic may be more suitable for linguists.SE where some of my "broader" questions have ended up. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly they're not recorded.

They're called Hesitation Markers, or various equivalent names. They are the various sounds people make when they're hesitating to think of what to say next, or to remember a word, or just because they've drawn a blank. Emitting one of these markers signals an intention to hold the floor, and to try to keep one's conversation partners from taking the floor and interrupting one. These markers vary, from group to group, and language to language.

They're phenomena of ***Speech***, though, not of writing. So, unless you're transcribing dialog, you shouldn't have to worry about how they're spelled. Which is good, because they're spelled any which way at all.

However, any spelling with an "R" in it comes from a non-rhotic dialect of English, like RP in the UK. And "UH" is a lame attempt to represent shwa - /ə/ - the commonest vowel in English, and the commonest hesitation marker. E.g,

- *He said ..* /ə/ *.. he said he wasn't ..* /ə/ *.. going to arrive on time.*

How you spell it is up to you. [The Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) hasn't ruled on that yet.

Comment: And even if you are transcribing dialogue, these sounds are usually omitted from the transcript.

Comment: +1 But because they're not usually recorded and vary from language to language, what sources do places like Etymonline use to date it (e.g. "attested from c.1600")? I don't think it's unreasonable to assume people centuries ago made the same noises; however, just as "like" has been recently appropriated as a hesitation marker, how would we know which markers came and went without written examples? Is it an extrapolation from words like [*haw*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=haw&allowed_in_frame=0) or just a "reasonable" assumption?

Comment: I have no idea where people get the ideas that they freely express about language and words. Since these markers are individual vocal twitches, consider what would be necessary to document the history of winking. Did Bill wink the **same** wink as Joe did? Or was it different? How could you tell now? How could you tell 200 years ago?

Comment: @JohnLawler I wasn't trying to be facetious. Sorry if the question is harebrained. The fact is, at some point English writers did document speech. I was curious as to when "uh" or "um" was first recorded. Perhaps centuries ago different markers were used, and it may not matter what they were save that they *were in use*. I also realize that asking why markers differ among languages is like asking why does any word for something differ. It was [this abstract](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract;jsessionid=58A793FD6C7A3D8C30D17D718C36D0BF.journals?fromPage=online&aid=1035916)

Comment: (cont.) that got me trying to formulate a question in the first place. Unfortunately, the article's behind a paywall and, as I'm not a linguist, it's probably beyond my ken anyway. I haven't learned anything I didn't know already, but I greatly appreciate the time you invested in your answer. It was helpful, nonetheless. I am accepting it and see no need for anyone to further look into what turned out to be a rather useless question. Thanks. :)

Comment: I could swear I have seen *um, er,* and/or  *erm* used in comments on this board, as a deliberate choice, to signify (somewhat facetiously) that the commenter was trying hard to be gentle or to euphemize, or was being compelled by another's dimness to point out explicitly something that ought to have been obvious. This seems to me a separate category of usage, a deliberate indication of intentional hesitation. See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122188/what-do-you-call-these-containers/122189#122189), for instance.

Comment: Yes, but of course it's the hesitation that carries any meaning; the sound is merely a personal floor-holding marker, with no significance and pretty random pronunciation. Saying UH on purpose (or UM, or UH-UH, or UH-HUH, or just HUH!) is a completely different matter, with completely different possibilities.

Comment: I do not think these words are "individual vocal twitches" since they vary across languages.  That they are used in a casual way hardly seems relevant; the dictionary doesn't decline to investigate the etymology or history of the word "toot" because it's imitative either.