# What do you call these containers?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was walking past a high school and I saw a container of cookies sitting on the handrail to one of its portables. The cookies: (I use an iPad so couldn't scale it down unfortunately :()

[image]

And I was wondering what do you call these containers, these transparent plastic containers? Is there a name for them?

Comment: plastic drums, perhaps? Or, may be "ops cookie trays"

Comment: It's a "tray".  Or, with the top on, possibly just a "box".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um, it looks like a "tray" to me. Perhaps the food packaging industry has a jargon name for it, but if so, I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it a "sleeve" of cookies.

Comment: I would call it a _sleeve of cookies_ if it was wrapped in plastic (much like [these](http://dyingbraincells.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/crackers1.jpg)), but I think the container itself would still be a *tray*.